# User-Select still copies to clipboard

Tags: html, css, copy-paste

I just discovered the `user-select` attribute of CSS. I was wanting to find a way for people to copy the displayed results on a page, without copying the headings as well (and a few other things).
Each browser is a bit different when they attempt to select something. But I've been testing mainly in Chrome. [**Fiddle Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/BnRdw/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="no-select heading">Heading 1 - can't select it</span>
    <p>This text you can select & copy.</p>
    <span class="no-select heading">Heading 2 - can't select it</span>
    <p>This text you can select & copy.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The results:

[image: user-select highlighting]

To me, it looks like they would only be able to copy the highlighted text. However, when copying what is highlighted - it does have `heading 2`, but it did not copy `heading 1`. **Why is this?**

```
This text you can select & copy.

Heading 2 - can't select it
This text you can select & copy.
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't really think its all that surprising, the [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property is to prevent a user from *selecting* an elements' content. Nowhere in the [Basic UI Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) does it mention the behaviour regarding copying content. I would imagine this is why there are variations among different browsers.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) also states:

> Controls the appearance (only) of selection.  This does not have any affect on actual selection operation.

The comments in this [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80159) report also say the same thing.

Comment: I would assume if they can't select it - then they wouldn't be able to copy it. But the quote from MDN is interesting. That it just gives the affect of not selecting. So maybe I should look for a better solution to prevent them from copying the headings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the following solution.
https://danoc.me/blog/css-prevent-copy/

html:

```
<p data-pseudo-content="Lorem Ipsum"></p>
```

css:

```
[data-pseudo-content]::before {
  content: attr(data-pseudo-content);
}
```